# Подключение к базе данных по SSH

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, ssh-tunnel

Столкнулся с проблемой: мне нужно получить данные с `Oracle` базы данных, которая находится на удаленном Linux-сервере.
Пробую библиотеку `sshtunnel`, но не получается. Пишет ошибку:

> TNS:connect timeout occurred.

Вот мой код. Что тут не так?

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import sys
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

db_host = 'XX.XX.XX' # ip базы данных, которая на удаленной машине

with open('ssh_private.ppk', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(file, sys.stdout)

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ХХ.ХХ.ХХХ', 22), # Хост и порт удаленной машины
    ssh_username="XXXX", # Логин к удаленной машине
    ssh_password='ХХХХХХХ', # Пароль к к удаленной машине
    remote_bind_address=(db_host, 1521),
    ssh_pkey='ssh_private.ppk', # ssh ключ
    ssh_private_key_password='12345', # Пароль ssh ключа
) as tunnel:
    tunnel.start()
    port = tunnel.local_bind_port

    db_dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(db_host, 22, 'SID')
    db_connect = cx_Oracle.connect('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX', db_dsn, encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")

    df_test = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM UAS022.MGART', con=db_connect)
    db_connect.close()

    file_xls = 'Report_test.xlsx'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_xls, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df_test.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test')

    writer.save()

    tunnel.stop()
```

Comment: Попробуйте для начала [сделать это в OS и убедится что все работает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653788/how-can-i-connect-to-oracle-database-11g-server-through-ssh-tunnel-chain-double)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте установить сначала соединение с обычным SSH клиентом, поведение [sshtunnel](https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/) не должно ничем отличаться.

Допустим, есть сервер с БД и SSH демоном, который доступен с `mysrv.com:6622`:

```
$ ssh me@mysrv.com -p 6622 
$ # Ok
$ ssh -N -L1521:localhost:1521 me@mysrv.com -p 6622 &

$ sqlplus -l me/me@localhost/service

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

Если так всё работает, то и в скрипте будет работать:

```
from cx_Oracle import connect, makedsn
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

host = 'mysrv.com' 
port = 6622

with SSHTunnelForwarder (
        (host, port), 
        ssh_username="me", ssh_password='pass', 
        remote_bind_address = ('localhost', 1521),
        local_bind_address  = ('localhost', 1521)) as tunnel:
    tunnel.start()
    dsn = makedsn ('localhost', 1521, service_name='service')
    conn = connect ('me', 'me', dsn, encoding="utf-8", nencoding="utf-8")
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute ('''SELECT 'connect working', 'ok' from dual''')
    print (curs.fetchall ())
    conn.close()
    tunnel.stop()
```

Результат:

```
$ python sshtun.py
[('connect working', 'ok')]
```